# How to get the item selected from ListVIew

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

ok, i hope you understand me...

i have a listView. The ListView is filled with a collection (List  lists) of data, but each item within the ListView has the same template (border, grid, border, textblock), so, how do I get the text property of the textblock when I select an item  ??

```
xmlns:vmSegments="using:EC_UsuarioWin8.ViewModels"


<Page.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateStyleSegment">
        <Border  Margin="-10,0,0,0" Background="White" >
            <Grid Height="120" Width="200">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0">
                    <Image Source="{Binding SegmentImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SegmentName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFE0241B" FontSize="20" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
                <vmSegments:ViewModelSegments x:Key="SegmentCollectionVM" x:Name="SegmentCollectionVM"/>
   </Grid.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="ListVIewSegments" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SegmentCollectionVM}, Path= SegmentList}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewSItemtyleECFood}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateStyleSegment}" SelectionChanged="ListViewSegments_SelectionChanged">
</ListView>

</Grid>
```

My Class ViewModelSegments:

```
public class ViewModelSegments : BindableBase
{

    private SegmentsCollection _segmentList = new SegmentsCollection();
    public SegmentsCollection SegmentList
    {
        get { return _segmentList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _segmentList, value); }
    }
}
```

My class SegmentsCollection:

```
public class SegmentsCollection: ObservableCollection<Segment>
{

}
```

My Class Segment:

```
public class Segment : BindableBase
{
    //Propiedad SegmentName
    private string Name;
    public string SegmentName
    {
        get { return Name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref Name, value); }
    }

    //Propiedad SegmentPicture
    private Uri image;
    public Uri SegmentImage
    {
        get { return image; }
        set { SetProperty(ref image, value); }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you binding your data through a view model.  Can you show some of your xaml?

Comment: sure!, I'll edit the post. Yes, i using data through a view model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thks to Inder Kumar Rathore and DJ Burb to guide me to find the answer.
so, here is

```
Segment seg= ListView.SelectedItem as Segment;
if (seg!= null)
{
    tbckChoiceSelected.Text = compa.CompanyName;//TextBlock called bckChoiceSelected
}
```

it was very easy. again, thnks.

Answer (score 5):

Use [**`ItemClick`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick.aspx) event of `ListView`

```
//Here sender is your list view
public delegate void ItemClickEventHandler(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
   ListView lv = sender as ListView;
   Segment seg = e.ClickedItem as Segment;

   if (lv != null)
   {
      //Use your lv if you want to
   }

   if (seg != null)
   {
      string name = seg. SegmentName;
   }
}
```

---

**Update**

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lv.SelectedItem; // If you have set SelectionMode="Single" then it will do
    //the trick but if you set SelectionMode="Multiple" then it's the first
    //selected item

    lv.SelectedItems; // It will give you the selected list of item view models

    e.AddedItems; //This will give you the added items. As it is a list so can
    //be multiple but when it can be multiple I don't know that case.

    e.RemovedItems; //Similarly removed items
}
```

Comment: yeah, it works, but, if i want to use this event, i have put "true" the IsItemClickEnabled property, and when tgis porperty is true, i cant selected a item in my ListView

Comment: lv.SelectedItem is null, therefore my listview is not selected

Answer (score 1):

In your view model create a property like this:

```
    public class ViewModelSegments : BindableBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

      private SegmentsCollection _segmentList = new SegmentsCollection();
      public SegmentsCollection SegmentList
      {
        get { return _segmentList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _segmentList, value); }
      }

      //Bind this property to your ListView SelectedItem property in the xaml

      Segment _selectedSegment;
      public Segment SelectedSegment   
      {
        get
        {
           return _selectedSegment;
        }
        set
        {
           _selectedSegment=value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedSegment");
        }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
      {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }

   }
```

In your xaml change your ListView to this:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListVIewSegments" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SegmentCollectionVM}, Path= SegmentList}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewSItemtyleECFood}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateStyleSegment}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSegment}" SelectionChanged="ListViewSegments_SelectionChanged">
</ListView>
```

Now whenever your ListView selection changes, the SelectedSegment changes with it, and then you can access the `SelectedSegment.SegmentName`

Comment: we are close, but no :(   i dont understand very well your class. Mi ViewModel class is called "ViewModelSegments", this class contains a collection of list (list of type Segments), within each list, I have my property SegmentName and SegmentImage

Comment: Is the type called Segment or Segments?  Basically, your I am assuming that your ViewModelSegments is this: List<Segment> ViewModelSegments ,right?   I am also assumming that the Segment class has properties Segment.SegmentName and Segment.SegmentImage. With that being said the property that I created above should bind to the ListView's SelectedItem (as shown in the xaml).  So, whenever the user selects the item in the listview the SelectedSegment will be the currently selected Segment and you can retrieve the the selected SegmentName through SelectedSegment.SegmentName

Comment: yeah, is called Segment, but my ViewModel have a Collection:           private SegmentsCollection _segmentList = new SegmentsCollection();
        public SegmentsCollection SegmentList
        {
            get { return _segmentList; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _segmentList, value); }
        }

Comment: my other class called Segment:                                                         private string Name;
        public string SegmentName
        {
            get { return Name; }
            set { SetProperty(ref Name, value); }
        }

        //Propiedad SegmentPicture
        private Uri image;
        public Uri SegmentImage
        {
            get { return image; }
            set { SetProperty(ref image, value); }
        }

Comment: look at my post again, i put the clases of my project.

Comment: Exactly.  So you should be able to add the property that I showed above to the ViewModelSegments class.  Then in your xaml bind that property to the ListView SelectedItem property like in the example I showed above.  Then you will have the SelectedSegment property at your disposal to get the currently selected Segment's SegmentName.  Try it and let me know if it works or not.  I will edit my answer to show you what I mean

Comment: yeah, i see, but... doesn work... the property SelectedSegment.SegmentName is null... obviosly, hasn't anything... because, when i use my class (ViewModelSegments), segment is null, SegmentList has a info data. u have my code, try to do, and you see that doesn't work. Tnhks! a lot!

Comment: Sorry forgot, you will need an INotifyPropertyChanged.  I'll change my code again, so you can see.

Comment: why u use INofityPropertyChanged if my class has a BindableBase ?... anyway, I tried the changes and I found an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, because SelectedSegment is null.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
        string items = "";
        foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems){
            items += "Item: " + item.Text + "\n";
            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem in item.SubItems)
            {
                items += "SubItem: " + subitem.Text + "\n";
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(items);
```